# Sitecore compare items version programmatically

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Lets suppose I have an Item with 5 versions. (I am not talking about language versions).

I would like to compare all the versions to identify the differencies. Is there some thing available out of box from Sitecore to do this task? Or I have have to loop over all the versions and then all the fields to find the differences.

Comment: Do not understand the question, You can use the version compair function in Sitecore, and select to different version of an item to compair. why loop over all versions?

Comment: Are you talking about this [Sitecore version compare](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/content_authoring/managing_items/cloning__versioning/view_and_compare_item_versions). I want to show info to normal users who are not content editors.

Comment: Yes, but I understand now that you want something for website visitors? so programtically, I don't think it is in Sitecore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing like that out of the box. You will have to compare fields one by one.

Remember that some of the fields should be ignored (like `__Updated`, `__ValidFrom`, `__Workflow State`, etc).

Remember that it's not easy to display what was changed in `Blob` fields.

And here is a code for you to start with:

```cs
FieldCollection fields = version1.Fields;
fields.ReadAll();
fields.Sort();
foreach (Field field1 in fields)
{
    if (field1.ShouldBeTranslated)
    {
        Field field2 = version2.Fields[field1.ID];
        var value1 = field1.Value;
        var value2 = field2.Value;
        ... // whatever you need here
```

Make sure you add all the necessary null checks! I skipped them for the clarity.